# How to change List<String> to List<dynamic> in Dart 2?

Tags: dart

I have a `List<String>` and I need to change it to `List<dynamic>` in Dart 2.

First, I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
var str_list = ["aa", "bb"];

// fails - is not dynamic
// gives List<String> 
List<dynamic> target_list_0 = str_list;
```

Later, I tried these 2 ways:

```
// succeeds - is dynamic
// gives List<dynamic> 
var target_list_1 = [] + str_list;

// succeeds - is dynamic
// gives List<dynamic> 
var target_list_2 = List<dynamic>.from(str_list);
```

It works but I am not sure it is the best (or idiomatic) way to fix the problem. I would like to write my Dart-2 code as clean as possible, could you help?

**Edit**

@matanlurey asked clear example where this pattern is necessary and how I am using it.

I am developing something like twitter but more complex (not only #hashtags and @mentions but words that have internal structure). So, I make some modification of the source text, then split it by whitespace (or parentheses) to words and then examine word by word. If the word is special I change the string to a map (containing parsed info). The change is happening in-place in the list. And that is where I need it `dynamic`. I have this source code:

```
var split_regexp = new RegExp(r"[^\s\(\)]+|[\s\(\)]+");
var body_matches = split_regexp.allMatches(body_part);

var body = [] + body_matches.map(
    (m) => m.group(0)
).toList();

// ... processing it ...
```

Currently, I am rewriting it from javascript (to which I rewrote it from python). Both the languages are able to catch the text by which I split words, it is much easier:

```
// python
body = re.split(r"([\s\(\)]+)", body)

// javascript
body = body.split(/([\s\(\)]+)/g)
```

Is it possible to write it so simple in Dart? I think not - because I need the splitter whitespace (or splitter parentheses or anything in future versions of my app) and dart `split` doesn't catch it.

Comment: I think that the `var target_list_2 = List<dynamic>.from(str_list);` is the cleanest as it clearly conveys that the purpose of the line is a list type conversion.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`List.from(...)` is going to be the most idiomatic way, today. In fact, [the style guide now recommends it](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-listfrom-unless-you-intend-to-change-the-type-of-the-result) if you are trying to change the type of an existing list:

```
// If you want to change the type, then calling List.from() is useful:

var numbers = [1, 2.3, 4]; // List<num>.
numbers.removeAt(1); // Now it only contains integers.
var ints = new List<int>.from(numbers);
```

> as clean as possible

Probably you *don't* want `List<dynamic>` at all, in that case. It might help if you can give clear examples where this pattern is necessary and how you are using it.

Comment: I have added requested info directly to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Good option is also:

```
var numbers = [1, 4]; // List<dynamic>
var ints = numbers.map((s) => s as int).toList();
```

Comment: The variable numbers is not a List<dynamic> type